# API is returning 0 for a field when the database has its true value in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

An API call to Spring is returning 0 for the `courseid` field of an `Event` entitiy, all other fields return the correct value.

in `EventController`

```
@GetMapping("/events")
    Page<EventVM> getEvents(Pageable page) {
        return eventService.getEvents(page).map(EventVM::new);

    }
```

`EventService`

```
public Page<Event> getEvents(Pageable pageable ) {

        return eventRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

then if I try this request in postman I get

```
{
            "id": 453,
            "eventname": "This is new",
            "courseid": 0,
            "date": "2021-12-12",
            "maxentrants": 12,
            "cost": 20.00,
            "eventtype": "4BBB",
            "qualifier": false,
            "info": "This is a test from react",
            "winner": null
        }
```

so `courseid` is showing at 0 when in fact it is `241`

To ensure I can get this value I made a simple getEvents in EventController,

```
@GetMapping("management/events")
    List<Event> getEvents() {

        return eventRepository.findAll();
    }
```

This returns all the values inc `courseid` correctly.

`courseid` in the `Event` table is a foreign key to `id` in the `Course` table. I thought this may have been the issue but it worked fine when I made the simple getEvents call.

Edited

```
 com.hoaxify.hoaxify.event.vm;

import com.hoaxify.hoaxify.event.Event;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EventVM {

    private Long id;

    private String eventname;

    private long courseid;

    private String date;

    private int maxentrants;

    private BigDecimal cost;

    private String eventtype;

    private Boolean qualifier;

    private String info;

    private String winner;

    public EventVM(Event event) {
        this.setId(event.getEventid());
        this.setEventname(event.getEventname());
        this.setEventtype(event.getEventtype());
        this.setDate(event.getDate());
        this.setCost(event.getCost());
        this.setInfo(event.getInfo());
        this.setQualifier(event.getQualifier());
        this.setMaxentrants(event.getMaxentrants());
        this.setWinner(event.getWinner());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is with the mapping to `EventVM`. Can you show its code? Thanks.

Comment: Edited to include EventVM class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Event` has a `courseid` attribute then you need to fix `EventVM` constructor as follows:

```java
public EventVM(Event event) {
    this.setId(event.getEventid());
    this.setEventname(event.getEventname());
    this.setEventtype(event.getEventtype());
    this.setCourseid(event.getCourseid());
    this.setDate(event.getDate());
    this.setCost(event.getCost());
    this.setInfo(event.getInfo());
    this.setQualifier(event.getQualifier());
    this.setMaxentrants(event.getMaxentrants());
    this.setWinner(event.getWinner());
}
```

Mind the added line `this.setCourseid(event.getCourseid());`.

Comment: Thanks. That's so annoying. Always the simple things I miss!!

Comment: If my answer helped you consider upvoting it and even accept it as the answer so that others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!